# GUI rendering problem in WINE with and without DXVK

Tags: graphics, windows, wine, gui, 23.10

I need to run together two windows programs inside Ubuntu/wine:

1. Omnisphere (GUI works with default wine rendering **but not with DXVK** (a Vulkan-based translation layer for Direct3D 9/10/11)-GUI renders only partly, mainly black window, in terminal it gives error `0af0:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIViewSettings"`)
2. and Spitfire Audio Abbey Road One (**doesn't work with default wine rendering** (need to resize window to get GUI updated), but perfectly works after [DXVK installation](https://github.com/doitsujin/dxvk)).

I know that I could configure a separate wine prefix for each of these programs, but the problem is, that I need to use them simultaneously inside FL Studio. How could I use them both? I don't care about speed, just the stability: the GUI to actually render stuff and to update when I click buttons and menus.
Currently I can only run these programs separately by manually running `winecfg` and switching override for libraries (d3d10core.dll, d3d11.dll, d3d9.dll, dxgi.dll) between [native] and [builtin] (recommendations, how can I do this faster with a script are also appreciated).

It there any stable (mayble not so fast) alternative to default wine rendering and DXVK?

Or maybe there is a more stable alternative to wine as a whole? (but, if possible, I would prefer to utilize wine folder, because it is huge and contains  many programs).

I use wine-9.0, ubuntu 23.10, DXVK 2.3.

The output of `inxi -G` is:

'''
Graphics:
Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel
Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX150] driver: nvidia v: 535.161.07
Device-3: IMC Networks EasyCamera driver: uvcvideo type: USB
Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.0 driver: X:
loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
resolution: 1: 2560x1440~60Hz 2: N/A
API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1 renderer: Mesa Intel UHD
Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
'''

(and the problem is the same on the second computer with a different video card).